# Format numbers in cells with text

Tags: excel

I have cells that look like this: `1000 (1.0)` and I would like to format the first part of the cell with commas separating the thousands, i.e `1,000 (1.0)`.

I've tried using the `text` function in a formula i.e. `=text(A1,"0,000")` or `=text(A1,"#,###")` but this didn't add a comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel sees the cell as a text string and as such it cannot be formatted.  You need to parse the string and put it back together:

```
=TEXT(LEFT(A1,FIND("(",A1)-1),"#,##0") & " " & MID(A1,FIND("(",A1),20)
```

[image]